# SQLite Database missing a table

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I have the following code snippet that creates a writable version of my .sqlite file on my test phone:

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // First, test for existence of writable file:
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pictures.sqlite"];

    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (!success){
        // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pictures.sqlite"];
        success = [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
        if (!success) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
```

The copy of pictures.sqlite that I have on my Mac has 3 tables, and is the most recent version of the database. The .sqlite file on my phone only has 2 tables, which reflects an older version of the DB. I cannot figure out how to update the phone to hold the new database. Can somebody help me do this?

Comment: Simplest is to delete and reinstall the app.

Comment: Side note: Using `NSAssert()` to report an error is not a good idea.  It's likely the release build will omit the assertion statement leaving the app to continue running under the assumption the database was copied successfully rather than reporting an error to the user and going into a controlled non-functional state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you app is started, check the version of the database. (In this case, check if the third table exists.)

If it is too old, update it. (That is, copy the new version from the resources, or manually create the third table.)